# Prove that $OM$ is dividing $\angle IOR$ into two.

Tags: geometry

The square $ORIT$ is a oblong . it is given that $TR=IM$, prove that $OM$ is dividing $\angle IOR$ into two equal angles.

added my try in the pic:
[image]

Please I'm stuck a few hours need help.

Comment: An "oblong square" is not a square.

Comment: And what exactly are we supposed to deduce that you have done from that picture? As far as I can see you have marked some angles and lines as identical, that's not impressive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\triangle OIM$ is isosceles, $\angle IOM = \angle IMO$

Also since $TM \parallel OR$,  from opposite interior angles, $\angle ROM = \angle IMO$,

From here you have the result.